# Vertical align with Bootstrap3 using inline-block trick

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Consider the example: http://jsfiddle.net/xExxp/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-4">
            <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2b/Small-logo.jpg' />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-8 vcenter">BAR</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have the CSS:

```css
.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Seems not working, any idea?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: You want to place BAR upon the logo ? Verticaly-aligned inside the row div?

Comment: recommended from adobovs: [Stackoverflow: vertical-align with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20548578/10075027)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If above image is the output you are looking for:

CSS:

```
.headerrow{
 display: table;   
}

.logoimage{
 display: table-cell;   
}
.vcenter {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row headerrow">
        <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-4 logoimage">
            <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2b/Small-logo.jpg' />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-8 vcenter">BAR</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Work partially but it affect the container width: http://jsfiddle.net/xExxp/2/ (Try to make the screen wider)

Comment: add width: 100% to your headerrow. .headerrow {
display: table;
width: 100%;
} it will fill the parent container now.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old question but for others who land here should be helpful this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/20548578/10075027

You have to apply `.vcenter` class to both `.col-` elements, also in some cases you have to use `<!-- -->` (you can use other type of comment it´s just for clear spaces between those elements)

Here is example using your .vcenter class

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-4 vcenter">
            <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2b/Small-logo.jpg' />
        </div><!--
        --><div class="col-xs-12  col-md-8 vcenter">BAR</div>
    </div>
</div>
```