# How to vertically center a div in a Bootstrap column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertically (and horizontally) center a div (height and width unknown) in a Bootstrap column. I can horizontally center the div by setting text-align to center. However I am struggling to vertically center the div. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12">
        <div style="text-align: center"> <!--this works-->
            <p>Content goes here</p>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also have a look at [Vertical align with bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Twitter Bootstrap and you have the Bootstrap 3, they added `<div class="center-block">...</div>`.

Reference: [Bootstrap v3.1.1](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.1.1/docs/css/).

Comment: Hey, thank you for you response. However I tried using the center-block class but it does not work Here's my code:  `<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12">
    <div class="center-block" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"> <!--this works-->
        <p >Content goes here</p>                
    </div>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: this is horizontal centering, still

Comment: the class "center-block" is for horizontal centering, not vertical centering.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to give this a shot:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 Outer">
      <div class="Inner>
         <p >Content goes here</p>                
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


/* CSS Code */

.Outer {
   border: 1px solid black;  /* Just so you can see it centered vertically */
   display: table-cell;
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 15em;    /* Set to height you need */
}
.Inner > p {
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Keep in mind that the browser will automatically recognize the resolution width; 
   however, the same functionality doesn't apply to height. You need to set a specified
   height on the outer element in order for the inner content to have something to
   vertically align itself to. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thank you very much. However it doesn't work. The paragraph get centered horizontally but it still remains at the top vertically.