# Vertically Center Content in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recognize that this question has been asked a hundred times. However, the answers that I see do not work in my situation. This makes me believe there is something additional in my content.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:6px; margin-right:6px;" ng-repeat="product in products">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
    <a>
      <h4>{{product.name}}</h4>
      <h5>{{product.description}}</h5>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
    <span class="pull-right">
      remove&nbsp;
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the remove [x] in the second column to be vertically centered in relation to the first column. Right now, the remove [x] is vertically centered across the top. I thought I could vertically center the content by doing the following:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6" style="float:none; display:table-cell; vertical-align:center">
    <span class="pull-right">
      remove&nbsp;
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Unfortunately, that did not work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you had a look at this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3 Seems it answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by adding a `line-height` to your "remove" link.

For example if you add this class to your link:

```
  .remove {
    line-height: 40px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

It will be aligned.

#### [Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/l6m4qT1T9h)

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd recommend you to add an additional class to the columns you want to work with. In your bare-bones example, it won't make a difference, but once you start adding more elements, you'll find out the advantages of managing elements by their re-usable class.

So, first step, a tiny change in your HTML. Not really needed since you could easily target (for example) `.col-xs-6` , but this is a general approach (as we're at it, I'd add a class to that row and remove that inline style)

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:6px; margin-right:6px;" ng-repeat="product in products">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 midvert">
    <a>
      <h4>{{product.name}}</h4>
      <h5>{{product.description}}</h5>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 midvert">
    <span class="pull-right remove">
      remove&nbsp;
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now that we can SAFELY target Bootsrap element without affecting the flow of the same re-usable classes in further uses, we simply give a [**vertical-align**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) to them, like this:

```
.midvert {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle
  }
```

See how the vertical align is added to the **CONTAINING BLOCK ELEMENT**, not the element you want to align itself. But of course, that won't do anything at all, because our `.remove` element needs some sort of defined height, so we add the following:

```
.remove {
    line-height: 4; 
  }
```

While the reasons for single numbers is open to discussion (you could use px, rem, em, %, etc), and I have seen that most people here use the px approach, I prefer to use single numbers. You can see the rationale here [Prefer unitless numbers for line-height values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Prefer_unitless_numbers_for_line-height_values) , but again, use as you please. You'll notice that **a number between 4 and 4.5** is the perfect fit, just resize window and see it by yourself.

I've [forked a Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ly9is7oGOE) to demonstrate the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have created [***`Fiddle`***](http://jsfiddle.net/qhr78mu6/1/) for you, Hopefully this work for you.

Please observe css tab where i have added `display:table-cell;` for other `col-sm-6` css class as well.

Comment: Thank you for trying. Oddly, it's still not working. It works in your Fiddle. However, it looks like you're not included Bootstrap.