# Center content of a row in a bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, centering

I have been trying to center vertically the content of my row (part of a bootstrap grid).

I tried to use the class `centered`

```
.centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

See the function part here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/164915/www/test.html#works

Comment: possible duplicate of [vertical-align with bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Please include any necessary, relevant code in your question. That link will most like not work in the future, when others might be looking for answers to a similar problem. See [ask].

Comment: do you mean the row itself or the content of the row?

Answer (score 1):

```
.centered{
   text-align: center;    
 }
```

and in your html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12 centered">
        <h1>text</h1>
        <p>more <br /> text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```