# Vertical align images evenly in Bootstrap 3 with respect to next column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I want to vertically align one or multiple images with a text (whose height is unknown). The images should be vertically centered:

[image]

The current HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="images/sampleimage.png" class="img-rounded img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        Text goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this without knowing the height of the text column?

**Edit**
I can now center align the images:
CSS:

```
row-xs-flex-center {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
@media ( min-width:800px ) {
    .row-sm-flex-center {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
    }
}
@media ( min-width: 992px ) {
    .row-md-flex-center {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
    }
}
@media ( min-width: 1200px ) {
    .row-lg-flex-center {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
    }
}
```

with the div changed as follows:

```
<div class="row row-sm-flex-center">
```

But the images stick on top of each other. Is there a way to evenly vertically distribute the images?

Comment: Have you looked at: [vertical-align with bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)?

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I can now center align the images (see edit) but the images are stacked on top of each other. I want the images to evenly vertically distribute as shown in the image above. Do you have an idea for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that using [Flexible box layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) is an option, we can distribute the extra vertical space of the first column between the images evenly.

We should `display` the first column as a `flex` container and change its direction from `row` (default value) to `column`, and then add `justify-content: space-around` in order to achieve the layout:

Expanding [@KevinNelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/482256/kevin-nelson)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27771750/1725764) which is inspired from [an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3/25517025#25517025):

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/marocuxavu/1/edit?css,output)** *(vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity.)*

```css
.row-xs-flex-center {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

@media ( min-width:768px ) {
 .row-sm-flex-center {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center; /* up to you */
  }

  .image-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start; /* or center */
    align-self: stretch;     /* make sure that the column is stretched */
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
@media ( min-width: 992px ) {
  .row-md-flex-center {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
  }
}
@media ( min-width: 1200px ) {
  .row-lg-flex-center {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-sm-flex-center">
    <div class="col-sm-3 image-container">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80" class="img-rounded img-responsive"/>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80" class="img-rounded img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text <br>
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```