# Vertically aligning <div>'s within Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

So I'm using Bootstrap's grids to create (particularly here) a description of some variable *T* and a slider corresponding to it. The problem is that these two guys are not vertically aligned by default (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkTGs.png)).

I wonder if I could fix this without majorly affecting grids (to make it look cozy in mobile version as well). The best option would be the solution using some **Bootsrap classes** (without using fixed pixel-size).

**P.S.** *Just in case if it's important, I'm using [jQuery UI Slider Pips](http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips) for my .slider.*

```
<div class="row">  
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
    <h4>T<br> <small>Some Description</small></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPD.** Using the following code for a parent is not an option.

```
.sliderParent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

It helps with a fixed positioning of *div*'s, but instead disables Bootstrap's grid transitioning from *col-sm-** to *col-xs-**

```
<div class="row sliderParent">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    ...
  </div>
 </div>
```

So if anyone can advice something else I would be very grateful. = )

**UPD.** I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3). Not exactly what I wanted, but at least the functionality does not suffer. Here is the class for children *div*'s:

```
.vcenter {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried display property flex ?

you can assign following properties to parent.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Though this is not using bootstrap classes, it would be not spoil the responsiveness.

Comment: Actually, it does affect on boostrap functionality, so the question is still open. See UPD.

Comment: can you elaborate on how it effected ?

Comment: I wrote in UPD, but in a couple of words... On large screens I have my two _div_'s together with _col-sm-3_ and _col-sm-9_. When transiting to _xs_ I want to position them above each other, with _col-xs-12_ on both _div_'s. This doesn't work because of _display: flex_.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row">  
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
    <h4>T <small>Some Description</small></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What you did was add a line break into the line. Was that what you were going for?

Comment: That doesn't matter. "br" just adds space to the first (child) "div" and has nothing to do with the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a height for those divs, then set a media query to remove that defined height when it reaches the particular bootstrap breakpoint.

Comment: That's a good, but not very nice solution. This will demand a lot of cases to consider. I thought there was a nice simple solution for this.

Comment: Vertical is never simple