# in Bootstrap col-xs-12 is not ocupying 100% width because the display: flex; property

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

[image]

I needed to vertical align the image from the left in my site which uses bootstrap. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3) everything is okay but when I resize to xs screens the property col-xs-12 shares space with the other column and is not taking the 100% width.
How should I make it respect the given space provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .vertical-align {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

I didnt read carefully [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)