# vertical align column in row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My row items are currently aligned to the top of my row:

[image]

Is there a way I can align them horizontally?

```
<div className="row well">
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">

        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">

        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">

            <Button bsStyle="default pull-right">
                <Icon type="user" /> xx People
            </Button>

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do I have to give my buttons a height for the fix to work?

Comment: Can someone explain why they've down voted my question too please? Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Someone downvote my answer too, and it's a correct answer

Answer (score -1):

Transform the button in an inline-block element to define the vertical align:

```
button {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```