# Bootstrap vertical align button inside div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is sample code

```
<section class="col-md-12"> 
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 pull-right">
    <button ><a href="" class=" text-center">Test Btn</a></button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Is there way to set vertical aligment to middle for button for all screens ? I currently do that with margin-top in media queries, but it is "too much" coding, and just to ask for any simpler ideas ?

Tnx,
P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vertical-align with Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Unrelated: You don't need the `<button>` element around the anchor tag. Just use `<a href="" class="btn btn-default">Test Btn</a>` (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons)

Comment: Tnx for suggestion...

Comment: @Gottz, I see that before aksing question but no success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the solution you want?

http://output.jsbin.com/solomikebe

Essentially, this is the code

```
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

where the container `div` has `parent` class.

Comment: I found something similar, but this also solve problem! Tnx

Comment: You're welcome. I always loved Flex and hence my solution revolves around it.

Answer (score 3):

`.align-self-center` will work.

eg

```
<section class="col-md-12 align-self-center"> 
</section>
```