# Bootstrap: How to align the button group in the center (vertically)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, center

In the following code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Element Selection</h2></div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="form-group">
       <h3><span class="label label-info">Element Segment</span></h3>
       <textarea class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 text-center" >
      
      <div class="btn-group-vertical">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">>></button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><<</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ALL>></button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><< ALL</button>
      </div>
      
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="form-group">
       <h3><span class="label label-success">Element Segment</span></h3>
       <textarea class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
</div>
```

now the result is below:
[image]

so I can I put the button group in the center position vertically. I searched and tried `vertical-align: middle`, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3

Comment: if you are able to give that row an id, I would do something like this: http://www.bootply.com/87KkKmPmqK

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Flexbox` with media queries [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/536/) (`1200px` is for `.col-lg-`)

```css
@media(min-width: 1200px) {
  .flex-row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer already posted by @Nenad Vracar, but you can also try this

```
 .flex-row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/2Lzo9vfc/537/)