# put a button in the middle of a panel vertically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is my code for a header panel and I want to show a button on right side and in the middle of header panel vertically and a text in the center of header panel
but button shows on top of header panel instead of middle.

```
  <div class="panel panel-info ">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center clearfix">
                <a class="btn pull-right" style="background-color:red"          href="createpages"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ></span></a>
                <h5  style="color:white">create pages</h5>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your issue , it might help or you can create a fiddle link for better clarity

```
 <div class="panel panel-info ">
   <button type="button" style="float:right">button</button>
   <h5 align="center">Text center</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: you just change some part of my code  which is not my problem, as I mentioned I just want to put the button in the middle of panel    vertically not in the center of panel horizontally.

Comment: then have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37073028/bootstrap-how-to-align-the-button-group-in-the-center-vertically