# Center an image vertically inside a div for a column

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is what I currently have:

```
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <hr class="small">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6" id="logo">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="logo.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5" id="description">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                              Text
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want to be able to center the image inside the column on the left, but I'm not exactly sure how.  I've tried to follow this one here but it didn't work properly.
[How to vertically align an image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)

Comment: you want to center it vertically or horizontal?

Comment: Sorry, I meant vertically. I've added it to the main post

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this? with your current css

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://codepen.io/tiagofabre/pen/LNagaB

Also there is a realy cool article about flex in this link:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh; 

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <hr class="small">
  <div class="container-fluid col-md-6 vertical-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 bg-green">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid col-md-6 vertical-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 bg-green">
      <div class="portfolio-item">Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that working to you, why don't you marks that as solved ?

Answer (score 0):

into parent div, add this class:

```
col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6
```

like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6" id="logo">
    <div class="portfolio-item">
        <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="logo.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `portfolio-item` position to relative and `img` to position absolute and give the image `top: 50%;` `transform: translateY(-50%)` https://jsfiddle.net/pu4L80gq/

Also you can use JS to determine image container height and image height to give `margin-top` to image or `padding-top` to the container :

(image container height - image height) would give you the rest space in the container then divide it on two and with this value you can center your image vertically https://jsfiddle.net/pu4L80gq/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imgContHeight = $('.img-container').height();
    var image = $('.img-container img');
    var imgHeight = image.height();

    image.css({
        marginTop: (imgContHeight - imgHeight) / 2
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried that but the problem is if the right row (`description`) is taller than the image it doesn't put it in the middle. If I specifically define the height of the image column then it works but if I don't it doesn't work

Comment: So the solution is giving fixed height to the image also see the edit.