# How to vertical align bootstrap

Tags: html

I have a text inside a col, and i would like to know how can i put this text in the middle of the col.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 "><img src="images/header/picture.png" alt="Menu"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 ">Perfile</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><img src="images/header/picture.png" alt="Menu"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3

Comment: No is not that what i'm serching.
This is what i got, and the red line is where should the text be:
http://s33.postimg.org/lmf4rxba7/Sin_t_tulo.png

Answer (score 0):

try this.

1. In the class row add style="text-align: center"
2. Then change class="col-xs-2", class="col-xs-7",class="col-xs-3" 
   to class="col-xs-12"

> Perfile

Comment: Why should i change it to col-xs-12? If i want to separate the two menus with the tittle?

Comment: so that it will be vertically aligned with the menus.

Answer (score 0):

## Bootstrap. How to align vertically the contents of the menu

I have four solutions. The first of these requires that images were the same height. In three others the images may differ in height.

---

### 1. line-height

You can set a property `line-height` for the text. `line-height` must be equal to the height of images. It is suitable when the text occupies one line and images have the same height.

```css
.put-in-the-middle {
  line-height: 80px; /* = height of the picture.png */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="pull-left"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/69c/fff/" alt="Menu"></div>
    <div class="pull-right"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x80/9c6/fff/" alt="Menu"></div>
    <div class="put-in-the-middle text-center">Perfile</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### 2. table-cell

You can transform blocks in table cells. Then apply `vertical-align: middle;` to them.

```css
.transform-in-a-table {
  display: table;
}
.transform-in-a-table div {
  display: table-cell !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.make-it-wide {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row transform-in-a-table">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/80x40/c69/fff/" alt="Menu"></div>
    <div class="make-it-wide text-center">Perfile</div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/120x80/9c6/fff/" alt="Menu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### 3. HTML table

```css
.make-it-wide {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/80x40/c69/fff/" alt="Menu"></td>
    <td class="make-it-wide text-center">Perfile</td>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/120x80/9c6/fff/" alt="Menu"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

### 4. inline-block + text-align-last

You can use the idea from [vertical-align with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20548578/6263942) with property [text-align-last](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last).

```css
.vertical-middle {
  text-align-last: justify;
}
.vertical-middle > div,
.vertical-middle > img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row vertical-middle">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x40/c69/fff/" alt="Menu">
    <div>Perfile</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80/9c6/fff/" alt="Menu">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is not a bad idea but... with code you are making my row bigger, i would like that the text get in the middle of the col, regardless of the size of the col ( i don't know if that is possible)

Comment: @kaskull In that case you can transform your blocks in table-cells. I've wrote secont solution in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Gleb!! That is what i was serching for! But now i got a little problem with your code. (I'm editing and adding the info, for some reason this message sended with out my permit :) )

Comment: Thanks Gleb!! That is what i was serching for! But now i got a little problem with your code. 
At the end of the menu it apears a white box after adding your code:
http://s33.postimg.org/5w5g9j6jj/menu.png

And this is the code:
http://s33.postimg.org/bb2qhoj4v/Captura.png

PD: if i delete logo_center style, the white box still appear!

Comment: @kaskull I think, your right column is wider than the image. How about tu change the layout to the HTML-table? I've added this variant to my answer.

Comment: @kaskull I've revised and redesigned my answer. Now I have 4 different solutions. I hope one of them will help you. Please let me know how things were going.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap class `text-center` to center your element in the column

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 "><img src="images/header/picture.png" alt="Menu"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 text-center">Perfile</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"><img src="images/header/picture.png" alt="Menu"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: But text-center put the text in the middle (horizontal) but not vertical