# How to vertically align <p> tag in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For my nav bar, I want to have my **p tag** line up with my **a tags**

CSS is here

```
#welcome {
    vertical-align: center;
    /* align: middle; */
    color: white;
}
```

HTML is here

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="welcome">
      <p>Welcome</p>
    </li>
    <li><a id="home" href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="logout" href="/logout.html">Log out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But this is what it looks like:

[image]

So how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: and note that I do not want to use another a tag for Welcome because I do not want to deal with the highlighting when you hover over it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vertical-align with Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Man there are many solutions available in many thread for this. In your case why don't you give some padding instead because the div is real small and it wont cause any problem if you do that.

Comment: what does this results `vertical-align-middle;`

Comment: vertical-align: middle; shows the same for me @Bhansa

Comment: post full code of html, css or create a jsfiddle

Comment: @SanketPatel HTML is posted

Comment: @nicael please see html above

Comment: @GandalftheWhite I don't want to use padding because I would rather they all have the same padding so that I don't run in to browser size issues down the road

Comment: I have used padding on logo image in the navigation bar and I haven't really faced any real problems in accordance to responsiveness because you can handle them separately anyway.

Comment: Does removing the `<p>` element's vertical margins help?

Comment: @GandalftheWhite I will give it a try then, thanks

Comment: @NateWhittaker I ended up adding a padding and got it work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way would be to give the p tag the same `line-height` as the height of the navbar and remove its margins:

```
.navbar p {
    line-height:40px;
    margin:0;
}
```

the `vertical-align` property does no align elements vertically despite what it looks like. It only works in table cells and on `inline-block` elements. Also there is no `vertical-align: center;` its `vertical-align: middle;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this :

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a id="welcome">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a id="home" href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="logout" href="/logout.html">Log out</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/mg4sfz6r/)

Answer (score 0):

The `vertical-align` property tells an `inline-block` element how to align to its `inline-block` siblings.

Therefore your problem can be solved with the following code:

```
.nav li { 
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```