# Bootstrap text and image vertical align

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

A classic question ... unfortunately I have not found an answer anywhere:

How can the text be positioned in the middle / vertically, in the Boostrap example below (for -md and -lg divices), and also to keep responsive design.

http://www.bootply.com/cWigMNHee0

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Get over bootstrap for this. Start using CSS flex-box for vertical and horizontal alignment. It works like a charm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3

Comment: fyi, it is often worth checking the **Related** links column on the _right-hand side of the current page_ - you may find the answer there already? Even if the exact answer is not there, I often find enough useful information, to work out a method of solving the issue.