# Bootstrap vertical align header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Tried many things and looked at some answers here, but it didn't work. 
I try to vertical align a header to an image. Please take a look at my Bootply at: http://www.bootply.com/SEKp0kHvfX

Edit: Here's also the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&amp;txt=350%C3%97150&amp;w=150&amp;h=150">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
     <h2>Please align me! :)</h2>
</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Sorry for being imprecise. I want to have the header in the middle height of the image.

It should look like this:

```
+----------------------+
|                      |
|                      |
|  IMAGE               | Header
|                      |
|                      |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: There is no CSS method of aligning elements that do not share a parent. Plus...vertically align how....at the top, middle...bottom... *what*?

Comment: I thought the parent is the "row"?

Comment: No...the parents are the column divs which **are** aligned at the top. The image and the heading are children of their respective columns...not the row.

Comment: I think you want this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D that's exactly the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.vcen {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

create custom css like this
bootstrap uses float: left as default

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 vcen">
   <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&amp;txt=350%C3%97150&amp;w=150&amp;h=150">
    </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 vcen">
    <h2>Please align me! :)</h2>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Try this out.
Hope this Helps.

Comment: I believe the OP wants the text to be placed to the right of the image and middle aligned to it. You have pushed the text to a a new row (below the image).

Comment: No, sorry. I want it in one row

Comment: The Question of OP is not at all clear.

Comment: then ask for clarification, don't just post an answer