# How can I make rows align vertically?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I align the `<img>` element vertically to the bottom with the element containing the text *"Trump knocks Mosul offensive"*, using the current markup?

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.beatthebottom {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            US election: 2 days to go
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            Emotions run high in final days of the campaign
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            Person yells 'gun' ... Trump whisked away
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            US election: 2 days to go
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            Reality Check: Whoppers of the campaign
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            World of troubles for next US president
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            Pope warns against walls ahead of election
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            Rudy Giuliani changes his story on FBI
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            Trump knocks Mosul offensive
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            'It's gone mad outside'
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            'It's gone mad outside'
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 beatthebottom">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/oreo27/pen/QGwOdp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vertical-align with Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with flexbox with the following steps:

**1.** Make your parent `.row` a flex container that can wrap. This will make the direct child flex items.

**2.** Make your child `.col-sm-8` element a flex container as well but with column direction.

**3.** Use auto margin top in the `.row` element containing your `<img>`.

```css
.beatthebottom {
  background-color: red;
}
.flex-container-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.margin-top-auto {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex-container-1">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            US election: 2 days to go
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            Emotions run high in final days of the campaign
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            Person yells 'gun' ... Trump whisked away
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            US election: 2 days to go
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            Reality Check: Whoppers of the campaign
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            World of troubles for next US president
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            Pope warns against walls ahead of election
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            Rudy Giuliani changes his story on FBI
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            Trump knocks Mosul offensive
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 flex-container-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            'It's gone mad outside'
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
            'It's gone mad outside'
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row margin-top-auto">
        <div class="col-sm-12 beatthebottom">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**[Revised CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNJzPx)**

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly. I'll study it to see how it works exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Add empty div with clearfix class right after the end of first row of the container. Clearfix clears float, so floating container get align to the top, which I think what you need.