# Vertically align text in a bootstrap anchor (button)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm struggling to vertically align text within a Bootstrap (3) `<a>` when it works properly in a `<button>`

The HTML :

```
<button class="btn">some text<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play pull-right"></span></button>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<a href="#" class="btn">some text<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play pull-right"></span></a>
```

The CSS :

```
.btn {
  width: 315px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ff38a4;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

And the output :

[image: Screen shot of unaligned images]

And a codepen of the problem : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyOaao

How do I align the text and icon centrally using an `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 4):

Prevents the specified value line-height:
[image]

Comment: This aligns the text, but not the icon. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObVoRp

Comment: In this case, add the vertical-align for icons:
.glyphicon {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle}

Comment: That doesn't work. It stays aligned to the top. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBNLPo

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
a.btn {
  background-color: #ff38a4;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 14px 14px 14px;
  width: 315px;
}
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ck0s48ab/

Here, like above you can use `display: flex;`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for your use cas but I just ran into this issue and I went with:

```
<a href="#" role="button"><button class="btn" type="button">some text<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play pull-right"></span></button></a>
```

Just wrapping the original button with an anchor tag.

Answer (score -2):

why do you use `</br></br></br>` ? 
[vertical-align with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)
might help you

Comment: -1: The OP is just trying to demonstrate their problem as clearly as they can, <br /> tags aren't the cause of the text alignment issue inside of the <a> element.