# Perfect way to align div next to image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two divs. First one has a image file and the other one has a username. I just want to align the second div vertically center just like this way.

[image]

But this one is not aligned perfectly. This screen already coded but the problem is that I still couldn't figure out the perfect way to align middle the user name div. I just use my naked eye and adjust padding.

Here is the my code

```
.tag-header {
    padding: 12px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.tag-header .tag-header-img {
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.tag-header .info {
    padding: 14px 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    line-height: 14px;
}

.tag-header .info p {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
.tag-header .time {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.info span {
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #b9b9b9;
}

<div class="tag-header">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <img class="tag-header-img" src="http://blog.couchbase.com/binaries/content/gallery/speakers/kirkk.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="info">
                    <p>John Stevens</p>
                    <span class="time">2 minutes ago</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/p4x7d3fq/)

Any solution?

Comment: It looks just like the image you attached...

Comment: You could also play with the height of the row, for example, give it height 60px and then the username padding 12px but that will effect responsiveness so you would have to take that into account as well.
I really don't see the problem here, your code matches the image you attached

Comment: you want a vertical align I guess ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3 I think

Comment: @odedta: Yes the code does match with image but not perfectly aligned. Yes I need a vertical align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres your fiddle updated https://jsfiddle.net/p4x7d3fq/5/ -- i added borders just so you can see.

Using `display:table-cell` you can achieve this, if you don't mind the slight changes, including the addition of a height to match that of your image.

Comment: make sure you also put `display: table;` on the main container div

Comment: It is. If you look at the fiddle there...^

Comment: This seems ok. But how can I make space between image and username div?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have done an ok job making them both have the same height, the image doesn't have to use `float: left;`, you can also use `display: inline-block;` on it and `vertical-align: middle;` on both the image and the name, this way you don't need them to have the same height.

Also, make sure you use Bootstrap properly, you first need a "container" div, in the container you put a row, and in that row you put columns.

You only put a div with a row class in a column div if you want more columns in that column.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Normally I used above mentioned structure but the fiddle I kept it short.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flexbox:

```
.info {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: This will not lead to desired result, for sure.

Comment: depends on which browsers the website has to run on, `display: flex;` is not universally supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox