# How to vertically center text in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Edited for better understanding:

```css
html,body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
}
#home {
 color: black;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../images/bg-1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: inherit;
    min-height:100%;
}

#home .vcenter {
 vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<section id="home">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
   <div>
  <h1 class="text-center vcenter">Heading</h1>
  <h3 class="text-center vcenter">Sub Heading</h3>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have tried the above but it's not working. I have used min-height in section id because i want the bg image to be full screen as per screen size but the text is not vertically and horizontally center.

**I want the text to appear center of page according to screen size.**

[image]

I want the headings to go where its written 1920x1080.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try giving a minimum height to the parent div? `header`

Comment: You can try adding `min-height:100vh` to `div` after `row`

Comment: Try using table with height 100% and width 100%, set cell text-align: center;
example:
<html>
<body>
<table width="100%" height="100%">
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center">Welcome</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: this may be helpfull to you .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27771750/6107715

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the `vcenter` class to `pagination-centered`. That should work. And adjust padding on top. No need to add custom dirty css to get things done.

```css
.section-content {
  padding-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="section-content">
                <h1 class="text-center pagination-centered">Heading</h1>
                 <h3 class="text-center pagination-centered">Sub heading</h3>
             </div>
          </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

Or if you wanted it to be vertically centered on all screen sizes:

```css
.section-center__full {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="section-center__full">
                <h1 class="text-center">Heading</h1>
                 <h3 class="text-center">Sub heading</h3>
             </div>
          </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: but then its not in middle of screen in big screens.

Comment: Thanks Worked For me. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to select this answer.

Comment: @Phoenix, It's okay I'm not after to votes. I'm just here to help and to learn also :)

Comment: @Leothelion, I added a lil bit of snippet on my answer above. Please let me know :)

Comment: @claudios thats my point. That you have to add little bit custom css to make it center :)

Comment: @Leothelion, Yeah. First option in simplest form. But needs to customize to meet our different needs.

Answer (score 2):

There can be many possible variants for this.

**Method # 01:**

Use css3 `flexbox`. You can use following `HTML` structure for this. In my opinion `.container-fluid`, `.row` and `div` inside `.row` is excess in this case.

```
<section id="header">
  <h1 class="vcenter">Heading</h1>
  <h3 class="vcenter">Sub heading</h3>
</section>
```

And following css:

```
#header {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

#header {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
#header .vcenter {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <h1 class="vcenter">Heading</h1>
  <h3 class="vcenter">Sub heading</h3>
</section>
```

**Method # 02:**

Use table properties. For this however you will need one more wrap. Use following `HTML` structure:

```
<section id="header" class="text-center">
  <div>
    <h1 class="text-center vcenter">Heading</h1>
    <h3 class="text-center vcenter">Sub heading</h3>
  </div>
</section>
```

And following css:

```
#header {
  display: table;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
#header > div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

#header {
  display: table;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
#header > div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
#header .vcenter {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="header" class="text-center">
  <div>
    <h1 class="vcenter">Heading</h1>
    <h3 class="vcenter">Sub heading</h3>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try using  `position:absolute` to you center div and give `100vh` height to your main div.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
#header .vcenter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
}
#header .vcenter h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="vcenter">
        <h1 class="text-center">Heading</h1>
        <h3 class="text-center">Sub heading</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks Worked as I wanted! Both answer does the job.

Comment: @manish nice answer  but just a suggestion, try not to use position until and unless its only last option. just a suggestion mate.

Answer (score -2):

Please try this code.

```css
html,body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
}
#home {
 color: black;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../images/bg-1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: inherit;
    min-height:100%;
}

#home .vcenter {
 vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

section{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  align-content:center;

}
```

```html
<section id="home">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
   <div>
  <h1 class="text-center vcenter">Heading</h1>
  <h3 class="text-center vcenter">Sub Heading</h3>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

you can view codepen link http://codepen.io/santoshkhalse/pen/oYoKMP

Comment: please read full question as op wants in middle of screen like he showed in image but not in vertically center only.