# Vertically center content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, css-tables

How can I vertically center the whole content of body in Bootstrap?
I've two row. I've tried with display: table-cell, but the rows stays in the same row (sorry for the words joke).

***HTML***

```
<div class="container container-table">
    <div class="row vertical-center">
        [...]
    </div>
    <div class="row vertical-center">
        [...]
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
html, body, .container-table {
    height: 100%;
}

.container-table {
    display: table;
}

.vertical-center {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you correctly, but you try `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` on `.container` or `.container-table`

Comment: what do you mean by vertically center??

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping both rows in a single "vertical-center" container.

```
<div class="container container-table">
  <div class="vertical-center">
    <div class="row">
      [...]
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      [...]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqfvu7wz/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try,

```
 .content-table{
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    display: block;
   }
```

No need for display table-cell