# Can I put a Rails partial between two arrows?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

So, I have a rails partial (an image of a car) that I want to put between two arrows ("<" and ">").

Here's my haml:

```
 .col-sm-12
   <
   = render partial: 'vehicle_image', locals: { quotation_request: quotation_request } 
   >
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't get the two arrows to show up on the same row as the image.
Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Comment: try `= "< #{render partial: 'vehicle_image', locals: { quotation_request: quotation_request }} >"`

Comment: thanks, but that didn't work, the image doesn't render now, I get "< <img id="vehicleimage" class="img-responsive" alt="" title="" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/happyfuncorp-com/image/fetch/s--fQjTfL9g--/http://localhost:3000/assets/no-image-0e7bb2077ff8fb073136596dc30e49c09971349cfc811a6651fc9ec85ffa2657.png" /> >"

Comment: apend `.html_safe` at the end

Comment: I did that and the image renders now but the arrows and the image still aren't lining up in the same row

Comment: Make the image 'display: inline' or 'display: inline-block'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably assign the arrows to some sort of element instead and lay things out like this

```
.row
  .col-sm-1.text-right
    <
  .col-sm-10
    = render partial: 'vehicle_image', locals: { quotation_request: quotation_request } 
  .col-sm-1.text-left
    >
```

You may have to do a bit of CSS to reduce the paddings/margins so that it that arrows end up where you want them exactly.

I just attempted it on a personal project using:

```
   .row
     .col-lg-1
       %h1
         <
     .col-lg-8
       = link_to place_path(place) do
         = image_tag place.main_image.url(:medium), class: 'img-responsive img-place', alt: place.name
     .col-lg-1
       %h1
         >
```

And got roughly this result after a bit of margin tweaking:

[image]

Comment: actually, when I changed the arrows to col-sm-2 and the image to col-sm-8, it worked, thanks!

Comment: glad to hear it :) 
You will probably have to tweak some CSS to get it fitting in a col-sm-1, perhaps the image exceeds the width of the div (e.g. it's not responsive).

Comment: as a followup question, do you have any idea how to vertically center the arrows?

Comment: looks like there's a bootstrap class for that too :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983183/vertically-center-content

Comment: alternatively it may just be a case of playing with `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`

Comment: the vertical-center thing didnt work, but adding padding to the top did! thanks again!