# div positions in a bootstrap well

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i have 3 divs in a bootstrap well
i want my btn-groups on the same line, the first on the left, the second in the center and the last one on the right

is it possible ?
i don't want to use an external CSS file

```
<div class="well">
<div>
    Unit of time
    <div class="btn-group">
        <!-- button -->
        <!-- button -->
        <!-- button -->
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    Offset
    <div class="btn-group">
        <!-- button -->
        <!-- button -->
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    Dates padding
    <div class="btn-group">
        <!-- button -->
        <!-- button -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you use bootstrap row and column concept?

Comment: @ManiRaj i'm begginer with bootstrap, it's not my field of expertise

Comment: No problem @RomMer , You can learn bootstrap in quick manner and its very easy.. There is a concept called row and columns learn and make use of it.. And also i posted an answer below which is a syntax of row column format.. It is very simple to split up 3 columns and you no need to use any css for seperation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's, you can simply use a grid, by adding each button group in a column, the three button in a row and the whole group inside a container

See an example there : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: and is it possible to vertical center my divs ?

Comment: Yes you can use an intermediate css class for it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 2):

You can get it 3 in a row by using bootstrap grid system as like,

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-4>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-4>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```